# What's an American synonym for the British expression "come up trumps"?

Tags: synonyms, american-english

Webster: British, informal
:to do or provide what is necessary in order to succeed ( especially when unexpected)
Ex: The team turned up trumps in the final game and won the championship.

I've been looking everywhere but no luck. Best I could come up with is " come through", but that's still a way off.

Comment: If you're playing Backalley or some such card game you could play the trump suite and win.  But to use that in games where there are no trumps would sound weird, although not incomprehensible.  In the US a ball-based analogy would be more popular: they pulled a hail-mary (i.e. football reference for a play that's a "long shot" [another option]) or some such.

Comment: Is that the main definition of the term? I thought it had at least as much to do with a fortunate outcome as the effort needed for such an outcome (it's an idiom based on the luck of the draw, after all).

Comment: Well, its bottom line is someone does something, especially where hope was lost, that turns the tide and makes things successful

Comment: But do you hear 'come up trumps' in the States?

Comment: "But do you hear 'come up trumps' in the States?" From British people.

Comment: By that definition, your own "come through" sounds about right, or maybe "come through **in the clutch**". Why do you say it's a way off?

Comment: Never heard "come up trumps" in the US.  One can roughly figure what it means, though, and idioms such as "long shot" and "hail Mary" don't really cover it, since those idioms generally leave unanswered the question of whether the action was successful.

Comment: "By that definition, your own "come through" sounds about right, or maybe "come through in the clutch". Why do you say it's a way off"- -- it doesn't imply the fact that it's at the last moment, or unexpected. Like in an action movie, when someone is about to be blown away and is saved by  someone who was out cold or something, who takes out the aggressor instead. That person 'came up trumps'

Comment: @1006a come through in the clutch is about the same thing though. That was the missing part to get it over the line. Thanks a lot

Comment: And I also found "come in clutch" on urban dictionary. Which one do you hear more often over there? Come through in the clutch or come in clutch?

Comment: @Daniel - I've never heard "come in a clutch".

Comment: It occurs to me "hit the jackpot" would fit some situations.  This generally refers to making a big win in a casino game, most particularly slot machines.

Comment: What is the connotation behind the “turned up trumps” phrase?  If seems like as a card game reference it’s a “pure luck” thing as opposed to a skill and poise thing like “pulled it off” or “came through in the clutch” etc.

Answer (score 2):

***pulled it off***, as defined by  [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+off):

> pull off something  also pull something off:   to succeed in doing
>   something difficult or unexpected.

Examples given by TFD:

> He won five straight games and pulled off one of the tournament's
>   biggest upsets.
>
> I don't know how you pulled it off, but we're now $5,000 richer than
>   we were yesterday.

In the OP's example:

> The team pulled it off in the final game and won the championship.

By coincidence, the *Washington Post* used the phrase today (09/22/17) in a story about Sen. McConnell's new drive for ACA [Obamacare] repeal:

> By the middle of next week, McConnell might **pull off** the victory
>   for  Strange [who is running for the seat vacated by Sessions when he 
>   became Attorney General] and have the votes lined up to pass the ACA 
>   repeal, which would his best week as leader since Trump took office. 
>   (emphasis added)

Answer (score 1):

I've heard the phrase ***pulling out all the stops*** for this sort of effect in common use in the US. Normally, this carries the connotation of removing the blocks and inhibitions one would have to jump in and do what needs to be done. Sometimes it is used as a desperation move, and in other cases, might simply be to go all out on something.

Likewise, to do something with ***no holds barred*** has a similar feeling.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "go above and beyond" is one example. There are probably others not coming to my mind right now.

"The team went above and beyond in the final game and won the championship."